# Adding new row in pandas in which two rows are connected

Tags: python, pandas, newrow

I have a data frame:

| 0 | Device 1 | Device 1 | Device 2 | Device 2 | Device n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 2 | Cannel 1 | Cannel 2 | Cannel 1 | Cannel 2 | Cannel n |

Since in row 0 there are several Device 1 and 2, up to n devices, I can not identify the right column.
To identify the right column I need to add a new line which connects row 0 and row 1. Or I need a code how I can identify the right loc.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like row 0 and row 2 should be used to build a (unique) multi-index...

Comment: Thank you. I tried to finde a solution how to apply your suggestion. I looked alot, but I only found examples for multi index of different collumns but not with different rows. As I wrote I am an absolute beginner with python and pandas.